# Fujitsu tablet PC. Ubuntu 12.04. and Lubuntu 14.04 rotate (xrandr) messed up pen and cursor

Tags: tablet, wacom

My tablet (fujitsu stylistic st5021) has wacom penabled which works splendidly with Ubuntu 14.04, except that it is very slow.

I tried loading Ubuntu 12.04 and discovered that the display app does not have the rotation feature. I used the `xrandr` command which rotated the screen to the left just fine but made the pen unusable since the cursor would line up with the pen at the very center of the screen, then its all over the place except under the pen nib.

Then I tried using Lubuntu 14.04 hoping that would do the trick, but no joy there either.

I would like the tablet to run quickly and have the pen usable. How can I achieve this?

Relevant tablet specs: 1.1ghz, 1.5gb memory, 1024x768 LVDS1.

Comment: You could try a newer version of Lubuntu: 16.04.1 LTS, 16.04.3 LTS, 17.04 LTS and in a few weeks 17.10 will be released. New versions come with new kernels and hardware drivers. Wacom Bamboo  works for me in Lubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, but I don't know if it will work with the tablet functionality. Try live (booted from a USB pendrive without installing), http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389 - I think 1.5 GB RAM is not enough for standard Ubuntu, but Lubuntu should do well.

Comment: hello worms, lubuntu 17.04 and 16.04 are complete failures. ubuntu 13.04 shows promise. pen(stylus) works nominally in all rotation modes, woohoo !! however ubuntu desktop is none existent. work around: copy apps to desktop folder. also, getting around bugs is sure a great learning tool. cheers all

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience :-) Please notice, that **13.04** passed end of life years ago, so there will be **no security updates**. It is OK to use it off-line, but do not connect it to the internet.

Comment: happy days are here again. updated 13.04 using old-release; enabled classic gnome (thanks to richard w @ liberian geek) i now have a very usable fujitsu pc tablet. cheers all !!!